# Creating and access a Settings class from the main file in Python

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I am attempting to create an alien invasion game, but I have ran into a snag getting my main file to import settings from my settings class. Below is my code, first my alien_invasion main file then my settings class:

### Main script

```
import sys

import pygame

from settings import Settings

def run_game():
    #Initialize game and create a screen object.
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))

    #Start the main loop for the game.
    while True:

        #Watch for keyboard and mouse events.
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        #Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.
        screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)

        #Make the most recently drawn screen visible
        pygame.display.flip()

run_game()
```

---

### settings class in same directory

```
class Settings():
    """A class to store all for Alien Invasion."""

    def __int__(self):
        """Initialize the game's settings."""
        #Screen settings
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color (230, 230, 230)
```

When attempting to run, I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "alien_invasion.py", line 28, in <module>
    run_game()
  File "alien_invasion.py", line 12, in run_game
    (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'screen_width'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is that the script? You have defined the name `Settings` twice inside it, once via the import statement and once via the class definition.

Comment: @Denziloe everything at class Settings() and below is on another file

Comment: Don't you think that would be useful information to put in your question?

Comment: My question clearly states if anyone has any ideas on why I am getting that error message.

Comment: And I am saying that people would like to help you, but nobody is going to be able to if you don't tell them unambiguously what your actual code is.

Comment: From the top of the post: "I am attempting to create an alien invasion game, but I have ran into a snag getting my main file to import settings from my settings class. Below is my code, first my alien_invasion main file then my settings class:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a typo is causing this problem, you are missing an `i` in your `Settings` class `__init__`.

Just for clarification the abbreviation `int` in Python stands for the Integer data type. `__init__` is short for "initialize".

Comment: Neither of those seem to be working, the first option gave me a "Settings class not defined" error, adding them both was the same result.

Comment: where is the settings module located in your path? is it in the same directory as your main script?

Comment: Yep, I have them both saved in the same folder. Which really makes it all the more frustrating as to why it isn't working.

Comment: can you create a gist or pastebin and link us to your whole code?

Comment: I accepted your edit, everything there is all I have so far, its the beginning of the project.

Comment: dude, you are missing an `i` in your `def __init__()`

Comment: that is your problem

Comment: Well that's embarrassing lol, also noticed I didn't put an = mark after bg_color. Now it works as expected. Thanks Riley!

Comment: no problem, I actually didn't notice either of those typos myself untill I cloned your gist and opened it in my editor

Comment: if you don't mind, please accept my answer if it worked for you

Comment: Accepted. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could fix this using:

from settings import *

As long as you don't have any overlapping variables, and the settings.py and the main.py are in the same directory, this should work.